# Что делать если бот переносит данные с одного пользователя на другого?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, aiogram

День добрый. Возникла нестандартная проблема. Бот переносит значения одного пользователя на другого. Т.е допустим:

Польз. А нажал на кнопку /start, но при этом еще ничего не сделал. Польз. B решил посмотреть пин-код своего заказа. Нажал на кнопку /start, нажал на кнопку проверки. И он его увидел, все хорошо. Однако, после того как пользователь A вернулся, и нажал кнопку проверки без повторного нажатия /start, он получает номер заказа пользователя В. ТОЛЬКО после повторного нажатия /start, пользователь A увидит свои данные.

Кстати, система проверки заказов использует MySQL. Т.е во время проверки, из базы данных запросом пин-код попадает в переменную, а оттуда уже показывается человеку сообщением.

Подскажите, как это возможно исправить, какие методы есть? Я буду на связи и могу предоставить все что будет необходимо

Используемый модуль: Aiogram 2.19

Comment: А вы вдруг глобальные переменные не юзаете?

Comment: Да, уже исправил. Спасибо огромное за подсказку!